# Как сделать чтобы в Edit text (андроид) после каждого введеного слова ставился знак _ вместо пробелов?

Tags: java, android

Например нажал ты пробел, а получилось "_"?

Исходный код:

```
o = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.mainEditText);
(findViewById(R.id.mainButton)).setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        startActivity( new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("мой текст"+o.getText() )));}});
```

И после этого в `EditText` или же "о" слова через пробел идут, а нужно чтобы вместо пробела ставился "_"

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

1. Повесьте onTextChangeListener на EditText
2. Проверьте в нём, что был нажат пробел.
3. Замените его подчёркиванием.

Answer (score 2):

```
 EditText eTxt;
```

...

```
eTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eTxt);

eTxt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    if (s.toString().contains(" ")){
        eTxt.setText(s.toString().replace(" ", "_"));
        eTxt.setSelection(s.length());
            }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо за отзыв, но это немного не то, что у меня оно ошибку выдавало. Я нашел выход попроще для тех кому будет интересно.

```
o=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.mainEditText);
k=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.text);

k=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.text);
(findViewById(R.id.mainButton)).setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity( new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://"+k.getText()+".m.wikipedia.org/wiki/"+o.getText().toString
                                                                    ().replaceAll(" ","_") )));
        }
    });

//vk.com/moto_ride_x


    }
}
```